# Can't Reference Static Files From RCL

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm working on a Blazor project, where I basically have 3 projects: `Client`, `Server`, and `Components`. `Components` is an RCL. The structure is similar to the following:

```
Components (RCL)
-- wwwroot/
---- js/
------ main.js

Client
-- wwwroot/
---- js/
------ main.js

Server
-- Startup.cs (in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app), calling `app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();`)
-- Pages
---- _Host.cshtml (in this file, referencing a main.js from the Components project like: <script src="_content/Components/js/main.js"></script>)
```

So `_Host.cshtml` in the Server project is the entry point. I'm trying to reference the main.js file from the **Components** RCL, by doing this:

`<scipt src="_content/Components/js/main.js"></script>    <<--- NOT WORKING`

But it's not working - I get a 404. I'm basing it on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets) and more specifically [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl).

Note that I am able to refer to main.js file in the Client project by doing this

`<script src="js/main.js"></script>    <<<--- WORKS`

But referencing static files in the RCL using the `_content/{library_name}/...` convention is not working.

What's the problem?

Comment: What is this strange requirement - why are you trying to use the JS file from a RCL in the server project, when the server project is serving up a Blazor Webassembly client - surely you want to use the RCL assets in the client project, don't you?

Comment: It's a fair question - I actually didn't create the project structure and setup, but I believe it is set up that way to be able to switch between server mode and client (webassembly) on the fly by simply injecting the blazor.server.js or blazor.webassembly.js file respectively. This is to allow support for IE11, which doesn't support webassembly.

Comment: Adding the version you are using may help. I have just created a new Blazor WebAssembly (client-side) project, [which refer to a RCL project](https://imgur.com/EzbXpKX) and it works (i.e, [can open the file](https://imgur.com/JyM8ogW)).

Comment: Also, make sure you have correct `{library_name}` as the Assembly name of your Components RCL project: https://imgur.com/NtgnzR2

Comment: I would check with the author of the project template, they must have had the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl), there are 2 lines you must include in the bootstrap files **in your consuming project** in order for static file references to work:

**1) Startup.cs > Configure() method** must include `app.UseStaticFiles();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // <<=== MUST INCLUDE THIS LINE

    ...
}
```

**2) Program.cs > CreateHostBuilder() method** must include `webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets(); // <<=== MUST INCLUDE THIS LINE
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

#2 is what I was missing. I'm not sure if I just missed that in the documentation or if they recently updated it to include that, but either way that fixed it for me.